# Send MultipleIterator to an email

Tags: php

my english may be confusing, i'll try to be specific. It's about PHP, here in stackoverflow i found a piece of code that is so near to give me what i want (an answer of ValkerK), i have two arrays to iterate into one and i found an answer to a question that was exactly what i was lookin for. I just need to create a variable and send the prints to an e-mail. It may be simpliest but i'm not exactly an expert, here is the code if you can help me, thanks for reading this.

```
$want = new ArrayIterator($_POST['product']);
$amount = new ArrayIterator($_POST['howmany']);

$it = new MultipleIterator;
$it->attachIterator($want);
$it->attachIterator($amount);

foreach($it as $e) {
 echo $e[0], ' : ', $e[1], ", ";
}
```

Then i have this prints

```
Product1:10, Product2:12, Product3:7.... etc
```

I need a variable to send that to an e-mail, but i still can't make it it work... thankes for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use something like this:

```
$contents = '';
foreach($it as $e) {
     $contents .=  $e[0] . ' : ' . $e[1] . ", ";
}
```

Now you can email `$contents`, which will contain the exact same output. You can also use [output buffering](http://www.php.net/ob_start), but for such a simple use-case, I wouldn't bother with it.

Comment: thanks, but i can't make it work, i think your answer is correct but when i work it online throw this error: 
Fatal error: Class 'MultipleIterator' not found in /home/termoaro/public_html/sendreq.php on line 17. do you know why? working with local server it seems to be working but online...

Comment: Because you're running an old version of PHP on the remote server.

Comment: that is php5 right? i just update it but it still don't work :(

Comment: But it has to be updated by the server administrator or me? it only has two options PHP4 and PHP5... this is bad... anyway thanks for your help and your answers, you were really helpfull... do you know any other method to do that, but without using php5.3.0?

Answer (score 0):

```
$var = implode("\n",array_map(function($v){
     return $v[0]. ':'. $v[1].",";
}, $it));
```

Comment: I did not understand how to use it... can you explain a little, i'm not that expert, it can be an option now, the actual server does not support PHP5 >5.3.0, so MultipleIterator can't be used, thanks!